# MySQL trigger not creating in custom wp plugin installation

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have made a trigger and I want WordPress to create this trigger on activation of plugin. I have tried many ways but failed to create trigger. But if I create through phpMyAdmin using SQL Query. PhpMyAdmin creates trigger. It means it does not have issue in syntax of trigger. But as I created through phpMyAdmin, on deactivation of plugin I wrote to delete trigger and trigger really deleted from phpMyAdmin. It means user has privileges to delete trigger. So If user has trigger deletion privileges then it is understood that user has also privileges to create trigger.

Here is the code:

On Activation Of Plugin:
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

```
global $wpdb;

$sql = "DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER message_filter BEFORE INSERT ON v2g_posts FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF(NEW.post_type = 'wpestate_message') THEN SET NEW.post_status = 'draft';  END IF; END;  $$ DELIMITER ;";

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

On Deactivation of plugin:
    global $wpdb;

```
$sql = " DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS message_filter; ";
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Here Is Complete COde:

```
 function message_filter_activate() {

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER message_filter BEFORE INSERT ON v2g_posts FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF(NEW.post_type = 'wpestate_message') THEN SET NEW.post_status = 'draft';  END IF; END;  $$ DELIMITER ;";

    $wpdb->query($sql);
 }
 function message_filter_deactivate() {

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS message_filter;";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
 }

 // register activation function
 register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'message_filter_activate');
 // register deactivation function
 register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'message_filter_deactivate');
```

Comment: Try removing the delimiter code (delimiter $$, end $$, delimiter ;).

Comment: After removing (delimiter $$, end $$, delimiter ;). It is showing syntax error. Kindly P.Salmon check this your self.

Comment: Dear P.Salmon. Please guide me. Your trick did not work.